# Understanding the image of a map between two Hom sets.

Tags: modules

I am working on a homework problem for a class and found that the part I am stuck on can be reduced to the following: Let $u: M \to M'$ and $v: N \to N'$ be module homomorphisms. I am trying to understand the map $(u,v): \text{Hom}(M, N) \to \text{Hom}(M', N')$. My main question is: if $f \in \text{Hom}(M,N)$, how do I determine what $(u,v)(f)$ is?

My initial guess was that its a function that results in a commutative square but wasn't able to show that the function I had in mind was well-defined.

Comment: that should be just composition shouldn't it? also you messed up the direction of one arrow (Hom is contravariant in the first variable). I.e. to get $$\mathrm(Hom)(M,N) \to \mathrm(Hom)(M',N)$$ you need $u: M' \to M$.
I would suggest you draw that as a small triangle on a piece of paper to wrap your mind around.

Comment: @Enkidu I found out the reason I was having difficulty was because this was a typo in both the textbook and homework assignment. I asked this question to my professor and he forgot to fix the typo. Thanks for your answer!